# Code looping through the column, but doesn`t add the result to the new table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, dynamic-sql

I have got a table where I need to summarise the column results based on value located in column, so I suppose like a pivot. Please see app. structure below. The idea is that document may contain hundreds of columns, so the code would have to be dynamic to pick up any changes by itself without any code amendments.

```
          Category          UOM A    UOM B    UOM C   UOM D
-----------------------------------------------------------
Article  | Apple | Mango     0        0        1       0
Pear     | Melon | Branch    1        0        0       0
Ball     | Box   | Table     0        1        0       0
Pear     | Melon | Branch    0        0        1       0
Ball     | Box   | Table     0        0        0       0
Article  | Apple | Mango     0        1        1       0
Pear     | Melon | Branch    0        0        0       0
Ball     | Box   | Table     0        1        1       0
Ball     | Box   | Table     1        0        0       0
Article  | Apple | Mango     0        0        0       1
```

What I have tried so far is to sum every column separately and then add to the new table. The code seems to be lopping through and summing the numbers, but not adding the result column to the new table.

```
if object_id ('tempdb..##TempSummary2') is not null
drop table ##TempSummary2
select distinct category into ##TempSummary2 from ##TempSummary
--select * from ##TempSummary2

declare @column as varchar(128);
declare @counter int;
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @counter = 8;

while @counter < 10
begin
    select @column = c.name
    from tempdb.sys.columns c
    inner join tempdb.sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
    where t.name = '##TempSummary'
        and c.column_id = @counter

set @sql = 'select a.*, sum([' + @column + ']) as [' + @column + '] from ##TempSummary2 a
            left join ##TempSummary b on a.category = b.category
            group by a.category'

set @counter = @counter + 1
end

exec (@sql)
```

So I would be expecting summary like the following

```
          Category          UOM A    UOM B    UOM C    UOM D
------------------------------------------------------------
Article  | Apple | Mango     0        1        2        1
Pear     | Melon | Branch    1        2        1        0
Ball     | Box   | Table     1        0        1        0
```

Comment: SQL is a set based language. There's seldom any reason to use loops. Explain what you want to achieve not how you thing it should be done. How did you get from the original data that's just a few 1s and 0s to 1567 somethings in the second row? What do the tables and columns look like? There are only 5 headers for 7 columns

Comment: Or are the vertical bars part of a *single* cell value instead of different columns? In that case, that's your problem. This is the most fundamental error in a database. A cell is supposed to contain an atomic value. Different types of data should go into different columns if not different tables.

Comment: Apologies, should have clarified, the words separated by vertical bar are concatenated into single column to get a unique path to the product

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off giving us some consumable sample data (tablular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements) along with some **readable** expected results as well.

Comment: If that's the case, @krokos format your sample data so that the headers and  columns align. Your data looks like `'Mango' ` is in the column `UOM B` and `UOM C` and a value of `'0   0'`. HOw do you "sum" `'0   0'` and `'0   1'` together?

Comment: Many thanks @Larnu for editing still exploring the editing functionality in there.

Comment: I *think* I've edited your data to be correct for what you have. I don't, however, understand your expected results. Where on earth does the value 1567 come from?

Comment: That still doesn't explain how 1 became 1567. In any case, hierarchical queries are handled using CTEs and/or the `hierarchyid` type, not joins, unless you know the number of levels in advance. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, explanations not my best side. 1567 is for an example only. So, sum comes as summation of al 1's in the column for the specific path.

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos it seems to be the way to go. Shall try to go recursive way

Comment: So you're saying that the expected results and the sample data you have have *nothing* to do with each other? How can we help you if the information we have is *wrong*? If you want help you need to give sample data and expected results that relate.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu my bad indeed. Have edited the result required

Comment: @krokos you still haven't explained what you want. What you posted looks like a simple `SELECT Category, SUM(UOM_A), ... FROM ThatTable GROUP BY Category`. There's no need for recursion with that data.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I need to sum up the numbers in every UOM column for every product path. I have tried to use group by but it comes back with Column '##TempSummary.UOM A' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That doesn't explain what is wrong with `SUM`, which works: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7696888d30428d5793f6d26f39f07551)

Comment: @krokos so add it - `SUM(UOM_A) as   UOM_A` or `SUM([UOM A]) as `[UOM A]` if the field name contains spaces

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos the problem is, if I have 100 columns, that would extra effort to amend all that data, so original idea of looping was to make it dynamic, so it would be picking up any changes in data. The column number can can constantly change and can add loads of overhead

Comment: @krokos that's not what you asked though. This is a *completely* different question.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I know. Thanks for your patience. Should have mentioned that as well.

Comment: @krokos not `as well`. It's the only relevant thing. You'll have to remove everything else and explain what you *actually* want - generate a dynamic SUM query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple SUM AGGREGATION with GROUP BY for your desired output as below-

**Note:** If your category resides in one single table, you can only use that one single column name in selection and GROUP BY clause.

```
WITH your_table(Category1,Category2,Category3,[UOM A],[UOM B],[UOM C],[UOM D])
AS
(
    SELECT 'Article','Apple','Mango',0,0,1,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pear','Melon','Branch',1,0,0,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ball','Box','Table',0,1,0,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pear','Melon','Branch',0,0,1,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ball','Box','Table',0,0,0,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Article','Apple','Mango',0,1,1,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pear','Melon','Branch',0,0,0,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ball','Box','Table',0,1,1,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ball','Box','Table',1,0,0,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Article','Apple','Mango',0,0,0,1
)

SELECT Category1,Category2,Category3 ,
SUM([UOM A]) UOM_A,SUM([UOM B]) UOM_B,SUM([UOM C]) UOM_C,SUM([UOM D]) UOM_D
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Category1,Category2,Category3
```

Output is-

```
Category1   Category2   Category3   UOM_A   UOM_B   UOM_C   UOM_D
Article     Apple       Mango       0       1       2       1
Ball        Box         Table       1       2       1       0
Pear        Melon       Branch      1       0       1       0
```